# Populando dropdown com json multinível

Tags: php, json, dropdown

Senhores, gostaria de uma ajuda.
Eu preciso popular um dropdown oriundo de um arquivo json

```
{
  "Categorias":
  [

    {
      "categoria": "Automação",
      "subcategoria": ["supervisório", "programação", "servidor", "hardware"]
    },
    {
      "categoria": "CFTV",
      "subcategoria": ["genetec", "servidor", "cabeamento", "ativo físico"]
    },
    {
      "categoria": "Controle de acesso",
      "subcategoria": ["sistema", "servidor", "controladora", "cabeamento/rede", "equip.físico"]
    }

  ]
}
```

Eu consegui fazer a chave categoria aparecer no `dropdown`, mas a subcategoria ocorre um erro.

```
<div class="item form-group">
    <label class='control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'>Categoria</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <select class="form-control">
        <?php 
            $arquivo = file_get_contents('teste.json');
            $json = json_decode($arquivo); 
            foreach($json->Categorias as $registro):
                 ?>
                 <option value="1"><?php echo $registro->categoria ?></option>
                 <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>          

<div class="item form-group">
    <label class='control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'>Sub-categoria</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <select class="form-control">
        <?php 
            $arquivo2 = file_get_contents('teste.json');
            $json2 = json_decode($arquivo); 
           foreach($json2->Categorias as $registro2):

                 ?>
                 <option value="1"><?php echo $registro2->subcategoria ?></option>
                 <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

No segundo `dropdown`, ocorre uma mensagem de erro:

> `(!) Notice: Array to string conversion`

Como faço para criar um `dropdown` somente com as opções de subcategoria?

Answer (score 1):

O campo `subcategoria` é um `array` de informações, então, precisa iterar sobre ele basicamente, ***exemplo***:

```
<select class="form-control">
    foreach($data->Categorias as $c): // Categorias
        foreach($c->subcategoria as $d): // subcategoria
           echo "<option value=''>{$d}</option>";
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
</select>
```

***Observação:*** *não precisa criar* `$arquivo2 = file_get_contents('teste.json');` *é redundante se pode usar o primeiro normalmente e as variáveis praticamente pode ser as mesma*.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Tem como eu exibir na segunda dropdown somente os valores referentes aos do primeiro dropdown?

Comment: Dá sim, mas, isso é outra pergunta e tem que ser feito outro questionamento. Ok?

Answer (score 0):

Bruce, sugiro que você faça um `foreach` adicional para subcategoria dentro do `foreach` das categorias, assim:

```php
foreach($json2->Categorias as $registro2):
    foreach($registro2->subcategoria as $registro3):
        echo '<option value="1">'.$registro3.'</option>';
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```